# Sort array on string date value not returning the correct result order (descending)

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I am trying to sort an array, on a string date, and I am having some issues with it.

My array is called: myArray and has the following sample info:

```
0: {…}
​​
deployed_date: "29/01/2019 14:08:44"
​​last_restored_date: "11/01/2019 11:22:22"

1: {…}
​​
deployed_date: "29/01/2019 14:08:19"
​​
2: {…}
​​
​​deployed_date: "29/01/2019 11:34:23"
​​
3: {…}
​​
deployed_date: "11/02/2019 11:24:33"
​​
4: {…}
​​
deployed_date: "11/02/2019 11:24:24"
​​last_restored_date: "11/01/2019 11:25:42"
```

I have used both Lodash and native JavaScript sorting, but unfortunately I am not able to sort on this deployed_date alone in descending order.

FYI, I am also using momentjs:

```
myArray[key].deployed_date = moment(value.deployed_date,'YYYYMMDDHHmmss').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
```

I have used:

`_.orderBy(myArray, ['deployed_date'],['desc'])` //lodash

as well as

```
myArray.sort()
```

The order is appearing as in my array above.

I'm not sure if it's to do with the fact that array indexes 1,2 and 3 do not have a `last_restored_date` value but for some reason, the array is not sorted correctly by deployed_date desc.

The result I expect is:

```
11/02/2019 11:24:33
11/02/2019 11:24:24
29/01/2019 14:08:44
29/01/2019 14:08:19
29/01/2019 11:34:23
```

How can I achieve the expected result order shown here?

Comment: what is the structure of myArray? is it an array of objects?

Comment: @MrJ yes it is.

Comment: after being sorted, you want just the dates in the output or the whole objects?

Comment: whole object but in deployed_date descending order, which is a string

Comment: Please try to refrain from txtspk here Tony - we're looking for readable, technical writing here as much as possible. This is not Facebook.

Comment: @halfer No problems. FYI, I don't do Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use moment library to firstly format the date in 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss' and below code will sort and returns result as you are looking for 

`x.sort((a,b)=>{
    return moment(a,'DD/MM/YYY HH:mm:ss').isAfter(moment(b,'DD/MM/YYY HH:mm:ss')) ? -1 : 1
})`

Comment: Hi. Am actually using moment - updated my post above.

Comment: then `moment(a,'DD/MM/YYY HH:mm:ss').isAfter(moment(b,'DD/MM/YYY HH:mm:ss'))` is comparing the dates and sorting it accordingly.

Comment: I have tried your solution having used `moment(a.deployed_date, 'DD/MM/YYY HH:mm:ss').isAfter(moment(b.deployed_date,'DD/MM/YYY HH:mm:ss'))` which seems to return the result set in a descending order. Is this b/c of the `isAfter` ?

Comment: if you want result in ascending order return 1 if condition satisfies else return -1 
like this :  `return moment(a,'DD/MM/YYY HH:mm:ss').isAfter(moment(b,'DD/MM/YYY HH:mm:ss')) ? 1 : -1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use map on the resulting array like this to obtain the expected result

```
let new_arr = foo.map( (obj) => {  
   return obj.deployed_date;
 );
```

Hope it makes sense

Comment: need this to be in descending order

Comment: if the sort is giving wrong input try to change the date to a timestamp before using sort and then reconvert it

Comment: Could you please provide a short example for the case - thanks.

Comment: I'll provide an example but i just saw maybe your problem for wrong short is the date format you should check that first as an easy and more better solution. your format is dd mm yyyy and it is expecting mm dd yyyy, I guess please check that first.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to map your dates to standard format when comparing the `deployed_date` of two objects using [String::localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare):

```js
const myArray = [
  {deployed_date: "29/01/2019 14:08:44", last_restored_date: "11/01/2019 11:22:22"},
  {deployed_date: "29/01/2019 14:08:19"},
  {deployed_date: "29/01/2019 11:34:23"},
  {deployed_date: "11/02/2019 11:24:33"},
  {deployed_date: "11/02/2019 11:24:24", last_restored_date: "11/01/2019 11:25:42"}
];

myArray.sort((a, b) =>
{
    let [aDate, aHour] = a.deployed_date.split(" ");
    let [bDate, bHour] = b.deployed_date.split(" ");
    let [aDay, aMonth, aYear] = aDate.split("/");
    let [bDay, bMonth, bYear] = bDate.split("/");
    let newADate = `${aYear}/${aMonth}/${aDay} ${aHour}`;
    let newBDate = `${bYear}/${bMonth}/${bDay} ${bHour}`;
    
    return newBDate.localeCompare(newADate);
});

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: how would I use your solution if I am using moment as described above?

Comment: @tonyf That was not there when I read the question. However, for what I can see `deployed_date` is a string because  `moment.format()` returns a string, so the previous should work. Have you any particular error?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const toDate = str => {
  const [d, t] = str.split(' ')
  return new Date(`${d.split('/').reverse().join('-')}T${t}Z`).getTime();
};

const compareByDate = (x, y) => toDate(y.deployed_date) - toDate(x.deployed_date);

const arr = [
  {deployed_date: "29/01/2019 14:08:44"},
  {deployed_date: "29/01/2019 14:08:19"},
  {deployed_date: "29/01/2019 11:34:23"},
  {deployed_date: "11/02/2019 11:24:33"},
  {deployed_date: "11/02/2019 11:24:24"}
];

arr.sort(compareByDate);
console.log(arr);
```

## Explanation

1. Convert each date into an ISO string date (standard format)
2. Extract a number from that string (using `Date.getTime()`) to facilitate comparisons. Use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor to change the string into a Date. Then convert that date into milliseconds
3. Since you want a decreasing order (reversed), make sure that in your *comparator function* you reverse the operands. `(x, y) => y - x;`
4. Once you have numbers as dates, you can use [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) based on the key `deployed_date`

## Note

The ISO format we want to use is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`. And since we have `29/01/2019 14:08:44` we need to do some processing.

1. Split the string with `' '` to separate *time* and *date*
2. Since the split return an array of 2 items, you can use the [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) operation.
3. Split the date with `'/'` and reverse the array, since we want `YYYY-MM_DD`. Then `join` using the `'-'` character
4. Create the date using `new Date(...)` then convert it into milliseconds using `Date.getMilliseconds()`

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, your usage of lodash’s orderBy is good and it should have ordered your data as expected. What’s causing you issues is that you're sorting strings not dates and your strings are in the format DD/MM/YYYY which is not ideal if you want to sort them: 01/01/2019 is « before » 31/12/2018 (although nonsensical).

What you can do:
1/ you can either have Date or Moment data instead of strings
2/ or format your dates as YYYY-MM-DD ... etc
3/ or pass a function to the sorting function ˋ_.orderBy(myArray, [d => moment(d.deployed_data, ...)], ['desc'])`